# How can I ignore "if" part if the "else" part is satisfied?

Tags: if-statement, assembly

As a beginner, I'm trying to solve this assembly exercise.

**Write a program to subtract (X-Y) and store the result in Z register, then:
Check if Z =0, add 50 to X reg.
else decrement Y reg. Let the PC = 100.**

I'm not sure if it's done like this, but according to my coursebook and lectures, I've achieved this result, ignoring the "if" part if the other part is satisfied.

```
100 SUB Z, X, Y
101 JZ 104
102 DEC Y
103 JMP 105
104 ADD X, 50
105 END
```

But I'm worried if the question is not asking to ignore the "if" part even if the other part is satisfied, which results in something like this.

```
100 SUB Z, X, Y
101 JZ 103
102 DEC Y
103 ADD X, 50
104 END
```

I have no clue which one is the correct answer to that question.
Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Your first code example looks correct.  For future questions, please post what architecture and (if applicable) operating system you are programming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual asm blocks look correct to implement the logic you intend them to, so the only real question here is how to interpret the original sentence.

The English sentence is constructed like an if/else statement in a programming language (like C), *not* like a proper English sentence.

If the context wasn't computer programming, then yes there's be some question whether the "add 50 to X reg" was unconditional.  But since it is, I'm sure they mean "check whether z=50: if so, then add ... else dec ....".

Or to phrase another way, "if z = 50, then add ... else dec ...".

Using the word "check" to introduce this if/else clause tripped up the sentence construction (because an if/else statement isn't a check, it's a decision *based on* a check).  And that led to it being not 100% clear whether you're always supposed to do the add.  **It's still 99.5% clear, though, in my opinion, so you should use your first bloc**k.  If you're still not convinced, email your instructor to confirm what they meant by their phrasing.

If they did mean your 2nd interpretation, that would be a very unlikely way to have chosen to write it.  There are *vastly* clearer ways, for example "add 50 to X, then, if Z isn't 0, decrement Y".  Unless your assignments are normally written as trick questions that are intentionally unclear, you can pretty much rule out that interpretation.

Either way, the "else" is an "else"; it doesn't have its own condition.  The "if" part has first chance at matching the condition.  It doesn't make sense to say "if the else part is satisfied" because the else part is only there as an alternative if the original condition *isn't* satisfied.  It doesn't have any conditions of its own.  It's only when you implement in asm and possibly reverse the condition to fall-through into the if body or jump to the else body that you get a logic reversal like that.  But you're still just *implementing* some logic that has a condition for the if part.